# String replacement not happening

Tags: tcl

I am reading line by line from file. In that file I want to replace
`#endif` statement with comment line as `/******/`. The following code is not touching that line

```
while {[gets $in line] !=-1}
{
     # if substring #endif is present in the string
        if { [regexp {endif} $line] } {

            set line [string replace "#endif" 1 7 "/*****/" } $line]
        }
 }
```

Comment: There are a number of syntactic problems with that code. Does it give any error messages when you try to run it? Those are usually informative…

Answer (score 1):

As @Donal wrote your "string replace" line has several issues - the "} $line" part is a syntax error, for one, and the range you are giving is longer than the string you are looking to replace. Maybe you meant:

```
set line [string replace ${line} 1 6 "/*****/"]
```

But that assumes the "#endif" part is hard coded to start from the second character of the line.

I think for what you asked it is simpler to use "regsub":

```
set line [regsub {#endif} ${line} {/*****/}]
```